# Java System.arraycopy resizes destination to source size?

Tags: java, memory

Hi I am trying to use System.arraycopy to copy a smaller array to a bigger one. This does work, but the destination is auto-resized to the source dimension.

I have to copy together a table for printing data. I want to copy 3 columns from table A into table C and than in a second step table B's 4th column als 4th column in C. The number of rows are in all cases the same. This idea fails because array copy seems to enforce the source dimensionality on the destination. This is kind of unexpected.

I do not want to iterate as this will take a long time if I use production-size data (>1 million or more rows)). I thought arracopy would be nice and fast solution.... any work arounds?

```
  public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[][] s = new Integer[2][2];

        Integer[][] d = new Integer[3][3];

        System.out.println(d.length + " " + d[0].length);

        System.arraycopy(s, 0, d, 0, 2);

        System.out.println(d.length + " " + d[0].length);
    }

}
```

This is how I call the API, anything wrong or is this resize avoidable?

Comment: Read the javadoc, it doesn't do any resizing. That would be crazy.

Comment: I updated my code, its a minimal working example now. Run it and see for yourself the size changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arraycopy` method definitely does not change the size of its argument arrays.

What is going on here is that you misunderstand how (supposedly) multi-dimensional arrays work in Java.

The reality is that Java arrays are essentially one dimensional.  For instance, a `String[][]` is actually an array of arrays of Strings.  When you use `arraycopy` to copy from one `String[][]` to another, you are not copying the references to the Strings.  Rather you are actually performing a *shallow copy* of the references to the `String[]` objects.  In your case, that is changing the number of columns ... according to your mental model of the array.

Remember, the `arraycopy` method simply does a *shallow* copy of the top level array.  It is simply treating the `String[][]` as an array of `String[]` objects ... and copying their references from the source array to the destination array.

If you want to keep the number of columns the same, the simplest way is to copy the elements with nested `for` loops.  I expect that if you profiled the code, you would find that the time you are saving with your use of `arraycopy` is small compared with the overheads of 1) performing the database query, 2) transferring the data through the resultset, and 3) copying it into a `List`, and 4) the `toArray(...)` call.

Here is the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) for the `arraycopy` method.  Note that there is no mention of resizing.

Comment: yes, allData is large enough for tokens and has additional more space for further columns (to be copied in later steps, not part of the code). 
After copying, allData equals tokens in size. 
Token has 3 columns and allData has 4, after copying allData shrink to 3. Is this avoidable?

Answer (score 1):

Your "resizing" comes from the fact that you're copying 2D arrays. Nothing is resized, it's overwritten.

```
s[0] = new Integer[2];
// Arraycopy copies s[0] to d[0]
d[0] = s[0];  // Therefore d[0] = new Integer[2];
```

You'll have to iterate the outer array and perform the arraycopy for each of the 2nd level arrays to avoid this "resizing".